# How can I prevent Android web browser from corrupting html?

Tags: android, html

We have a custom web browser that decodes pages delivered via a http module. This solution woks on all devices except Android because the browser is corrupting the html. For example, the html that is delivered might look like...

```
<!— Comment tag -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body etc…
```

But by the time the browser displays the page the html looks like…

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body etc…
```

As you can see, something has stripped both the comment tag and the doctype tag. We need to prevent that from happening and after hiring several freelancers, we have not found a solution.

We don’t need the doctype but we do need to preserve the comment tag because it serves as a flag for the browser to decode what follows. The browser is based on Webview and Kotlin.

Could a html filter be doing this? And can it be customized to leave comment tags alone?

Comment: When you say "custom web browser" you mean that you re developing your own HTML interpreter? or youre just using a WebView

Comment: It uses WebView.

Comment: Why you need the comments of the source code?

Comment: As mentioned above, the comment tag serves as a flag to tell the browser that what follows has been encrypted.